# nginxを使っているインスタンスでELBのproxyProtocolを有効にすると400(Bad Request)エラーが発生する

Tags: aws, nginx, amazon-elb

アクセス元のIPアドレスをELBのproxyProtocolを有効にして取得する際に
BadRequestが発生してそもそもページが表示できません。

■ ELBのリスナー
80(TCP) -> 80(TCP)
443(SSL) -> 80(TCP)
※proxyProtocolは80に対して有効にしています

■ アクセスログについて（**個人的にはここが怪しいと思いますが、何をどう調査すればいいのかわかりません・・・**）
現在、 **$status** の中身が 『PROXY TCP4 .....』となっています。
他の参考サイト様をみると、『GET ....』となるのが正常のようです。

アクセス元のIPアドレスを取りたいということが目的で、Teratailにも質問を上げています。
https://teratail.com/questions/26850
現在の設定ファイルの内容はTeratailを見ていただければと思います。

何かご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたら、ご教授願います。
（こういう調べ方をした方がいいんじゃない？等のご助言でも有りがたいです。）

よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: ところで[SSH](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell)は[SSL](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security)の誤りではないでしょうか。HTTP以外をSS**L**に載せる場合を指して、HTTPSとは別に書かれているようですが、SS**H**は全く別のプロトコルです。 http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/elb-listener-config.html

Comment: あっ・・・・記載ミスです。訂正しておきます・・・。ご指摘ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BadRequestの原因として、
nginx内に80をHTTPとしてListenしているVH環境が他に存在していたからと思われます。

現在、

TCP/SSL通信をするELBは内部的に80以外の別ポートを使用し
HTTP/HTTPS通信をするELBは内部的に80のポートを使用するように分けました。

今のところ問題なく動作しています。

Answer (score 1):

ELBのProxyプロトコルを有効にし、サーバ側でもProxyプロトコルに対応させて実現することも不可能では無いかもしれませんが、かなり特殊な方法になります。

一般的には、
　Webアプリから元のIPを知る：HTTPヘッダの X-Forwarded を確認する
　ログに元のIPを残す：WebサーバのログではなくELBのログを利用する or
                   Webサーバのログ設定を変更してHTTPヘッダの X-Forwarded を追加する
というのが簡単です。

また、sshをELBを使って振り分けさせるのは適切ではないため、sshは各EC2インスタンスそれぞれに直接アクセスするのが良いかと思います。

Comment: sshをELB使うのは適切ではないため、sshは各EC2インスタンスそれぞれに直接アクセスするのが良いかと思います。
ELB -> EC2（複数台）という形になると思うのですが、ELBへのアクセスはどうなるのでしょうか？


ちなみに、今回の場合websocket通信をしておりますので、HTTP/HTTPSではなくTCP/SSHでの通信にしています。
また、アクセス元のIPはNodeサーバー側に渡す必要があります。